# How does IE8 Determine if user is on dial-up or broadband

Tags: internet-explorer

How does IE8 determine that the user is in dial up or bandwidth, to determine max connections per host?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304129(v=vs.85).aspx